# How to use EOF to run through a text file in C?

Tags: c, file, eof

I have a text file that has strings on each line. I want to increment a number for each line in the text file, but when it reaches the end of the file it obviously needs to stop. I've tried doing some research on EOF, but couldn't really understand how to use it properly.

I'm assuming I need a while loop, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

How you detect EOF depends on what you're using to read the stream:

```
function                  result on EOF or error                    
--------                  ----------------------
fgets()                   NULL
fscanf()                  number of succesful conversions
                            less than expected
fgetc()                   EOF
fread()                   number of elements read
                            less than expected
```

Check the result of the input call for the appropriate condition above, then call `feof()` to determine if the result was due to hitting EOF or some other error.

Using `fgets()`:

```
 char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
 while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stream) != NULL)
 {
   // process buffer
 }
 if (feof(stream))
 {
   // hit end of file
 }
 else
 {
   // some other error interrupted the read
 }
```

Using `fscanf()`:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (fscanf(stream, "%s", buffer) == 1) // expect 1 successful conversion
{
  // process buffer
}
if (feof(stream)) 
{
  // hit end of file
}
else
{
  // some other error interrupted the read
}
```

Using `fgetc()`:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)
{
  // process c
}
if (feof(stream))
{
  // hit end of file
}
else
{
  // some other error interrupted the read
}
```

Using `fread()`:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, stream) == 1) // expecting 1 
                                                     // element of size
                                                     // BUFFER_SIZE
{
   // process buffer
}
if (feof(stream))
{
  // hit end of file
}
else
{
  // some other error interrupted read
}
```

Note that the form is the same for all of them: check the result of the read operation; if it failed, *then* check for EOF.  You'll see a lot of examples like:

```
while(!feof(stream))
{
  fscanf(stream, "%s", buffer);
  ...
}
```

This form doesn't work the way people think it does, because `feof()` won't return true until *after* you've attempted to read past the end of the file.  As a result, the loop executes one time too many, which may or may not cause you some grief.

Comment: Nice, but some suggestions of this popular answer: 1) “Function: `fscanf()`result on EOF or error :number of succesful conversions less than expected" equates an input “error” with format conversion failures.  Not a correct grouping IMO. Suggest another column  OTOH it is a complicated function 2) spell check 3) Suggest “bad Code” comment on `while(!feof(stream))` example.

Answer (score 15):

One possible C loop would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        /*
        ** Do something with c, such as check against '\n'
        ** and increment a line counter.
        */
    }
}
```

For now, I would ignore `feof` and similar functions. Exprience shows that it is far too easy to call it at the wrong time and process something twice in the belief that eof hasn't yet been reached.

Pitfall to avoid: using `char` for the type of c. `getchar` returns the next character cast to an `unsigned char` and then to an `int`. This means that on most [sane] platforms the value of `EOF` and valid "`char`" values in `c` don't overlap so you won't ever accidentally detect `EOF` for a 'normal' `char`.

Comment: see my answer i defined  a eof

Comment: @streetparade: To what effect?

Comment: A valid character value from `getchar` can *never* overlap with `EOF` on any conforming platform, because characters returned by `getchar` are in the range of `unsigned int` (therefore non-negative), and `EOF` must be negative.

Comment: @caf: That's what I thought until it was pointed out to me that there are platforms with 32-chars and 32-ints. This means that char -> unsigned char -> int can end up negative. Hence '[sane]'.

Comment: Oh yes, and good advice about ignoring `feof` - in my experience, use of that function almost always indicates a bug.  Testing the return value of the most recent input function call is sufficient and correct in 99% of cases.

Comment: I would say that on such a platform, the for the `getchar` implementation to be conforming it would have to take pains that unsigned character values greater than `INT_MAX` are either mapped to a value less than `INT_MAX` or ignored completely - mapping them to negative integers would be non-conforming, since it would not be "an integer in the range of `unsigned char`".

Answer (score 0):

You should check the EOF after reading from file.

```
fscanf_s                   // read from file
while(condition)           // check EOF
{
   fscanf_s               // read from file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use fseek-ftell functions.

```
FILE *stream = fopen("example.txt", "r");

if(!stream) {
    puts("I/O error.\n");
    return;
}

fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(stream);
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);

while(1) {

    if(ftell(stream) == size) {
        break;
    }

    /* INSERT ROUTINE */

}

fclose(stream);
```