# does the read call in linux add a newline at EOF?

Tags: c, linux, newline, eof

why does read() on a file in linux add a newline character at EOF even if the file really does not have a newline character ?

my file data is :

```
1hello2hello3hello4hello5hello6hello7hello8hello9hello10hello11hello12hello13hello14hello15hello
```

my read() call on this file should hit EOF after reading the last 'o' in "15hello". I use the below :

```
while( (n = read(fd2, src, read_size-1)) != 0) // read_size = 21
{
    //... some code
    printf("%s",src);
    //... some code
}
```

where fd2 is the file's descriptor. At the last loop, n was 17 and i had src[16] = '\n'.  So......, does the read call in linux add a newline at EOF?

Comment: You should probably show the output of `cat -n data.txt` in your question. Also see [How to use read() to read data until the end of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3180126/608639) and [How to use EOF to run through a text file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835986/608639)

Comment: `hd` will show you what exactly is in your file, by presenting the character codes in hexadecimal. (Some people prefer `od` -- octal dump.) `man hd` for more info.

Comment: @jww : $ cat -n testdoc2.txt 
     1 1hello2hello3hello4hello5hello6hello7hello8hello9hello10hello11hello12hello13hello14hello15

Comment: @rici : it shows a dot at the end. and for the dot, it gives the hex value 0a  |lo14hello15.|

Comment: The `0a` at the end is a newline character. So it was in the file all the time. `man ascii` if you need a table.

Comment: rici : got it. thank you rici :) . I will have to figure out why that newline gets in somehow.

Comment: @Jayanth If you're using a text editor to create the input file, depending on which one you're using, it can be difficult or impossible to create a file without the trailing newline.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Looks like its the text editor. My question does look incorrect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the read call in linux add a newline at EOF?

No.

Your input file likely has a terminating newline in it - most well-formatted text files do, so multiple files can be concatenated without lines running together.

You could also be running into a stray newline character that was already in your buffer, because `read()` does not terminate the data read with a `NUL` character to create an actual C-style string.  And I'd guess your code doesn't either, else you would have posted it.  Which means your

```
printf("%s",src);
```

is quite likely undefined behavior.

Comment: read() does not add a '\0' at the end. Even if I do not add a '\0', I see that when I allocate char str[30], the first 30 characters are all '\0' values by default.      Created this test file using a C++ code which does not print a '\n' at the end. I open the file in gedit to make small edits but neither I nor gedit would add any newlines to it. I am confused too, because the man page for read() does not mention newlines. And, the question here is about the newline (not the '\0').

Comment: @Jayanth You have misunderstood Andrew Henle's comments.  He's saying that because `read` does not add a `'\0'`, but `printf("%s"` expects one, `printf` could be reading past the end of the `n` characters read by `read` and finding a stray `\n` character somewhere in random memory off to the right of the `src` array.

Comment: @Jayanth Also, you said "when I allocate char str[30], the first 30 characters are all '\0' values by default", but depending on how and where you allocated `str`, the 0-fill is necessarily guaranteed; you might have gotten that result by accident.

Answer (score 0):

*why does read() on a file in linux add a newline character at EOF even if the file really does not have a newline character ?* **No**, `read()` system call doesn't add any new line at end of file.

You are experiencing this kind of behavior because may be you have created text file using `vi` command and note that default new line gets added if you have created file using `vi`.

You can validate this on your system by creating a empty text file using `vi` and then run `wc` command on that.

Also you can read file data using `read()` system call all at once if you know the file size(find size using `stat()` system call) and can avoid `while` loop.

This

```
while( (n = read(fd2, src, read_size-1)) != 0) { 
   /* some code */
}
```

Change to

```
struct stat var;
stat(filename, &var); /* check the retuen value of stat()..having all file info now */
off_t size = var.st_size;
```

Now you have `size` of file, create one dynamic or stack array equal to `size` and read the data from file.

```
char *ptr = malloc(size + 1);
```

Now read all data at once like

```
read(fd,ptr,size);/*now ptr having all file contents */
```

And at last once work done, Don't forgot to free the `ptr` by calling `free(ptr)`.

Comment: `stat(fd,&var);` is wrong.  That should be `fstat( fd, &var );`  `int size = var.st_size;` is also wrong, as [the `st_size` field of a `struct stat` is of type `off_t`.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)

Comment: Agree @AndrewHenle Let me modify it.