# Trying to count the number of lines in code, but getting stuck in infinite loop in C

Tags: c

I have been trying to create a function to count the number of lines of code. This is what I have come up with, but it is getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
int numberoflines(char filename[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    while( EOF != (ch = getchar())){
        if(ch == '\n'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: How come `getchar()` would magically know which file you expect it to read from?

Answer (score 9):

It's not an infinite loop, it's just that you aren't reading from the file you opened, but from standard input. Try `getc(file)` instead of `getchar()`.

Comment: I would also suggest that OP look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835986/how-to-use-eof-to-run-through-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: Question gives a clear idea about the usage and return values of various file I/O functions. Just thought it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in an infinite loop, it's reading from standard input, probably the terminal, because you used `getchar()` instead of `getc(file)`.

You should also `fclose(file)` before you return.