# How can I navigate through an array of strings of any length in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, gets

*Understanding handling direct pointers in C*

Here is a code that works for an array of strings for fixed number of items and fixed line length :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXNAMELEN 100
#define MAXLINELEN 100
#define MAXITEMS 1000

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

 FILE * infile, * outfile;
 char name[MAXNAMELEN];
 char line[MAXLINELEN];
 char lines[MAXITEMS][MAXLINELEN];
 int i, items = 0;

 printf("Enter a source filename: ");
 fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 infile = fopen(name, "r");
 while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile)) {
        strcpy(lines[items], line);
        items++;
 }

 qsort(lines, items, MAXLINELEN, strcmp);

 printf("Enter a destination filename: ");
 fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 outfile = fopen(name, "w");
 for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
    fputs(lines[i], outfile);
 }

 fclose(infile);
 fclose(outfile);
}
```

**Problem description and code**

If I try to read an input.txt file that is within `MAXLINELEN` and `MAXITEMS`, the program works fine. Now imagine I am reading from a much larger "inputfile" line by line where maximum line length could be anything, then I would have to use a character pointer (`char*`) to read the input. `char* linesptr[MAXITEMS];`

Here is my code where I am trying to accomplish reading from an input file   line by line delimited by a newline character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXNAMELEN 1000
#define MAXLINELEN 1000
#define MAXITEMS 100000

char* linesptr[MAXITEMS];

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {

 FILE * infile, * outfile;
 char name[MAXNAMELEN];
 char line[MAXLINELEN];

 int i, items = 0;

 printf("Enter a source filename: ");
 fgets(name, MAXNAMELEN, stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 printf("%s infile \n",name);
 infile = fopen(name, "r");
 while (fgets(line, MAXLINELEN, infile)) {
    int length = strlen(line);
    line[length-1] = '\0';
    linesptr[items] = line; *<- I am writing to the same mem location*
    printf("the input string %d is : %s \n",items,  linesptr[items]);
        items++;
 }

 qsort(linesptr, items, MAXLINELEN, strcmp); 
 printf("Enter a destination filename: ");
 fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 outfile = fopen(name, "w");
 for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
    fputs(linesptr[i], outfile);
 }

 fclose(infile);
 fclose(outfile);
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I am copying the pointer address into the  nth cell of the array `linesptr` where nth is the `value=items` (Here is the reference line from the code: `linesptr[items] = line;`). so when you print the final answer, I am referencing the same memory address to the buffer named `line`, the memory location at `line` will always point to the most recent `fgets()`. I understand the error but I do not know how to fix the issue. I would appreciate any help to fix the bug in the code.

Comment: Use `malloc()` to allocate a string dynamically, then copy from `line` to that string with `strcpy()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read unknown number of lines from stdin, C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537662/read-unknown-number-of-lines-from-stdin-c)

Comment: imagine using `getline()` and `realloc()`  then the code is ever so much simpiler

Comment: @user3629249 : Can you illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a example, so here it is:

the following proposed code:

1. is written for readability
2. checks for and handles error conditions
3. makes use of `getline()` and `realloc()`
4. is not as efficient as it could be because it calls `realloc()` for every line in the source file.
5. properly/safely uses `strcspn()` for removing any (possible) trailing newline characters
6. could have simplified the code by extracting the 'cleanup' to a sub function rather than repeating the same 'cleanup' code when ever an error was encountered.
7. used `size_t` rather than `int` for indexes into arrays to avoid implicit conversions
8. minimized the `scope` of variables where possible
9. passes proper third parameter to `qsort()`
10. properly implements the `compare()` helper function for `qsort()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAXNAMELEN 1024

// prototypes
int compare(const void *, const void *);


int main( void )
{
    printf("Enter a source filename: ");
    char name[ MAXNAMELEN ];
    if( !fgets(name, sizeof( name ), stdin) )
    {
        perror( "fgets for input file name failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets for input file name successful

    name[strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0'; // strip newline
    printf("%s infile \n",name);

    FILE *fp_in = fopen(name, "r");
    if( !fp_in )
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen for input file successful

    char **linesarray = NULL;
    size_t numLines   = 0;

    char   *line      = NULL;
    size_t  lineLen   = 0;

    while( getline( &line, &lineLen, fp_in ) != -1 )
    {
        char ** temp = realloc( linesarray, (numLines+1) * sizeof( char* ) );
        if( !temp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            fclose( fp_in );
            for( size_t i = 0; i< numLines; i++ )
            {
                free( linesarray[i]);
            }
            free( linesarray );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        linesarray = temp;
        linesarray[ numLines ] = line;
        numLines++;

        // prep for next iteration
        line = NULL;
        lineLen = 0;
    }

    free( line );
    fclose( fp_in );

    //puts( "all file read in" );

    qsort( linesarray, numLines, sizeof( char * ), compare );

    //puts( "file sorted" );

    printf("Enter a destination filename: ");

    if( !fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) )
    {
        perror( "fgets for output file name failed" );

        for( size_t i = 0; i< numLines; i++ )
        {
            free( linesarray[i]);
        }
        free( linesarray );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets() for output file name successful

    name[strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0'; // strip newline

    FILE *fp_out = fopen(name, "w");
    if( !fp_out )
    {
        perror( "fopen for output file failed" );

        for( size_t i = 0; i< numLines; i++ )
        {
            free( linesarray[i]);
        }
        free( linesarray );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen for output file successful

    for (size_t i=0; i<numLines; i++)
    {
        if( fputs(linesarray[i], fp_out ) == EOF )
        {
            perror( "fputs failed" );
            fclose( fp_out );

            for( size_t i = 0; i< numLines; i++ )
            {
                free( linesarray[i]);
            }
            free( linesarray );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    fclose( fp_out );

    for( size_t i = 0; i< numLines; i++ )
    {
        free( linesarray[i]);
    }
    free( linesarray );
}


int compare(const void *ls, const void *rs )
{
    char *leftSide  = *(char**)ls;
    char *rightSide = *(char**)rs;
    return strcmp( leftSide, rightSide );
}
```

Comment: Sneaky use of `line = NULL;
        lineLen = 0;` to get `getiline()` to do the `strdup()`.   I'd expect a `free(line)` after the while loop to not leak memory.  [This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: note: the pointer returned by `getline()` in the variable `line` is being saved into an entry in the array `linesarray[]` so cannot pass to `free()` until done with that array

Comment: "pointer returned by getline() in the variable line is being saved into an entry in the array " --> except for the last call of  `getline()`.  So if the loop ends because `getline()` returned `NULL` or `if( !temp )` path, `line` is not free'd and thus a leak.

Comment: @chux,  `getline()`, at end of file, returns -1, not NULL.   However, I do agree, that I should have passed the final entry in `line` to `free()`.  I'll edit the posted code.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the line to a dynamically-allocated string.

```
while (fgets(line, MAXLINELEN, infile)) {
    int length = strlen(line);
    if (length > 0 && line[length-1] == '\n') {
        line[length-1] = '\0';
        length--;
    }
    char *linecopy = malloc(length+1);
    strcpy(linecpy, line);
    linesptr[items] = linecpy;
    printf("the input string %d is : %s \n",items,  linesptr[items]);
    items++;
}
```

And if you want to handle more than `MAXITEMS` lines, you should allocate `linesptr` using `malloc()` as well. When you get to the current size of `linesptr` you can use `realloc()` to make it longer. See [Read unknown number of lines from stdin, C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537662/read-unknown-number-of-lines-from-stdin-c) for detailed code.

See [How to qsort an array of pointers to char in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489139/how-to-qsort-an-array-of-pointers-to-char-in-c) for the proper way to sort an array of pointers to strings.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. :) It worked.. Now I have the input in "linesptr" variable. When I pass this to the built-in qsort() method, it throws segmentation fault. How do I overcome this?

Comment: ---- I fixed ^^.. Basically, I had to change the following line in the code from "qsort(linesptr, items, MAXLINELEN, strcmp); " to "qsort(linesptr, items, sizeof(char *), strcmp); "

Comment: That's what I said in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. I have another follow up question. The qsort() method doesn't sort my input. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate help with this too. Basically, I am reading from an input file that has the following text in it: 

how are you?
hello there
somewhere over the
rainbow

This is how my output looks like:
how are you?hello theresomewhere over therainbow

Comment: `strcmp()` is not the correct comparison function, because it doesn't dereference the pointer. I've added a link to another SO question that shows how to do it correctly.

Comment: Oh yes, strcmp() works for multidimensional arrays not pointers. Thanks so much for all the help! :) My code works with the new changes.

Comment: Pedantic point: `line[length-1] = '\0';` begins a hacker exploit of _undefined behavior_ when the first character read in a line is a _null character_. Recommend   `if (length > 0 && line[length] == '\n') line[--length] = 0;  linecopy = malloc(length+1);`

Comment: @chux How can `fgets()` ever return an empty string? If there's nothing to return you must be at EOF, so it returns `NULL` and the loop exits.

Comment: "the first character read in a line is a null character" results in `line[0]==0`.  Say input was `'\0'`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'\n'`.  `fgets()` returns non-`NULL`.

Comment: Also by testing `if (length > 0 && line[length-1] == '\n')`  (corrected from above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997273/how-can-i-navigate-through-an-array-of-strings-of-any-length-in-c/50997315?noredirect=1#comment89047110_50997315)), code will not lop off the last character in the last "line" from a file that does not end with a `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks. I got that right in another question I answered a few days ago, somehow didn't think of it this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working solution to read in a file (big data), sort it and write it to a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXNAMELEN 1000
#define MAXLINELEN 5000
#define MAXITEMS 100000

char* linesptr[MAXITEMS];

int compare_function(const void *name1, const void *name2)
{
  const char *name1_ = *(const char **)name1;
  const char *name2_ = *(const char **)name2;
  return strcmp(name1_, name2_);
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{

 FILE * infile, * outfile;
 char name[MAXNAMELEN];
 char line[MAXLINELEN];

 int i, items = 0;

 printf("Enter a source filename: ");
 fgets(name, MAXNAMELEN, stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 infile = fopen(name, "r");
 while (fgets(line, MAXLINELEN, infile)) {
    int length = strlen(line);
    line[length-1] = '\0';
    char *linecopy = malloc(length);
    strcpy(linecopy, line);
    linesptr[items] = linecopy;
    items++;
 }

 qsort(linesptr, items, sizeof(char *), compare_function);

 printf("Enter a destination filename: ");
 fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
 name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
 outfile = fopen(name, "w");
 for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
    fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", linesptr[i]);
 }
 fclose(infile);
 fclose(outfile);
}
```