# feof(in) != EOF doesn't make while loop stop when at the end of file?

Tags: c, file

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("input.txt","r");
    char c = fgetc(in);
    while(feof(in) != EOF)
    {
    printf("%c",c);
    c = fgetc(in); 
    }
}
```

`feof(in) != EOF` doesn't stop the while loop from stopping but something like `!feof(in)` seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what EOF actually is?

Comment: End of File indicator

Comment: Change `feof(in) != EOF` to just `!feof(in)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835986/how-to-use-eof-to-run-through-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: In which case does `feof` returns `EOF` ??

Comment: What does the man page say?

Comment: Close, but not a dupe of `while(!eof(in))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feof` doesn't return `EOF` on end of file; it returns `true`, which is not equal to `EOF`.

`fgetc` *will* return `EOF` when it hits end-of-file.  Your code should be written as

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("input.txt","r");
    int c = fgetc(in);             // note int not char
    while(c != EOF)                // compare c to EOF
    {
      printf("%c",c);
      c = fgetc(in); 
    }
}
```

You should not use `feof` as a loop condition, as it won't return `true` until *after* you attempt to read past the end of the file, meaning your loop will execute once too often.

Comment: Note, though, that the loop condition in his code always happens right after a read and he doesn't use `c` unless the loop condition is true... so using `feof()` should work also.

Comment: Note: Subtle difference between this good solution and OP's (had it been `while(!feof(in))`).  This code will quit the loop should end-of-file or input error occur.  OP's code (corrected) only quits the loop on `end-of-file,